# Why can this function not be eta-reduced further?

Tags: haskell

I have a simple function:

```
calculate :: Int -> Int -> Int
calculate x y = sum . filter even $ enumFromTo x y
```

It can be reduced to

```
calculate x = sum . filter even . enumFromTo x
```

But it cannot be reduced further to

```
calculate = sum . filter even . enumFromTo
```

Why is this?

I expected it to compile, but I instead got following error:

```
    • Couldn't match type: Int -> [Int]
                     with: [Int -> Int]
      Expected: Int -> [Int -> Int]
        Actual: Int -> Int -> [Int]
    • Probable cause: ‘enumFromTo’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘enumFromTo’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘filter even . enumFromTo’
      In the expression: sum . filter even . enumFromTo
   |
10 | calculate'' = sum . filter even . enumFromTo
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: "eta reduction" means replacing `f x = g x` by `f = g`, for arbitrary functions `f` and `g`. Note how you only got your first transformation into this form by replacing a `$` with a `.` (in an implicit step which you didn't show). It's not so straightforward to write the transformed form (with one argument) in that form. It can be done but will look more complex and less elegant than your attempt.

Comment: Go backwards: `calculate = sum . filter even . enumFromTo` eta-expands to `calculate x = sum (filter even (enumFromTo x))` which in turn eta-expands to `calculate x y = sum (filter even (enumFromTo x)) y`. That however passes `y` as a second argument to `sum`, not to `enumFromTo`, hence it causes a type error.

Comment: The thing you really need to remember about eta-reduction is that the pattern you're looking for isn't just "the same variable on the end of the LHS and RHS source code **text**". It's structure of the the AST *implied* by the text that matters, not the structure of the text.

Answer (score 5):

The core issue is this:

```
calculate x = (sum . filter even . enumFromTo) x -- could be eta-reduced
calculate x = sum . filter even . (enumFromTo x) -- cannot be eta-reduced
```

If you'd like to eliminate `x`, you must first get it into a position where it really is the only argument to the outer-most function. (In this case, the outer-most function is `(.)`, not `enumFromTo`.) For example, let's write `s g` for `sum . g` and `f g` for `filter even . g`. Then:

```
sum . filter even . enumFromTo x
=
s (filter even . enumFromTo x)
=
s (f (enumFromTo x))
=
s ((f . enumFromTo) x)
=
(s . f . enumFromTo) x
=
((sum .) . (filter even .) . enumFromTo) x
```

This is an application of a function to the only argument, `x`, so now we can eta-reduce.

```
calculate = (sum .) . (filter even .) . enumFromTo
```

Comment: And `calculate = fmap (sum . filter even) . enumFromTo` by `fmap f . fmap g` = `fmap (f . g)`

Answer (score 0):

As Robin Zigmond pointed out in a comment, eta reduction is simply the recognition that if `f x = g x`, then `f = g`.

We'll rewrite your equation using some temporary variables and using prefix function application to make it easier to see how to get to the appropriate form.

```
calculate x = f . enumFromTo x where f = sum . filter even

            -- switch to prefix form

            = (.) f (enumFromTo x) where f = sum . filter even


            -- let g = (.) f

            = g (enumFromTo x) 
               where f = sum . filter even
                     g = (.) f


            -- definition of composition

            = g . enumFromTo $ x
               where f = sum . filter even
                     g = (.) f
```

Now we can apply eta reduction a second time.

```
calculate = g . enumFromTo
             where f = sum . filter even
                   g = (.) f
```

If we want, we could unroll the temporary variables and go back to using `.` solely as an infix operator, but the result isn't necessarily any more readable than this. Composition of "multi-argument" function is inherently messy, involving partial application of `(.)` itself, as seen in the definition of `g`.